# Add String to Camel Exchange Header from Route

Tags: java, header, apache-camel

I'm working on adding some functionality to an existing Camel route for a colleague. The route utilizes a call to an adapter that will do everything I need done already, with one exception, the method being used by Camel has the following signature.

```
    public void logCustomEvent(MyForm form,
        @Header("myHeader") String myHeader,
        @Header("myBoolean") boolean myBoolean) { ... }
```

I want to handle a scenario in this route, where nothing needs to be done. So we just jump straight into the `logCustomerEvent` adapter method, but that also means that the `myHeader` String value will not have been populated in the header yet.

I found the `.setHeader(String, Expression)`, so I'm curious if there is an easy way using MVEL or Simple or anything else to create an Expression in the route that will essentially insert a null String into my header with the name I provide it.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that there is NO header with the key=myHeader. And this is OK with you, and when this happens, you just want Camel to ignore this and pass in NULL as the parameter value?

Comment: We could like add optional parameter, so you can do @Header(name = "myHeader", optional = true) String myHeader

Comment: @ClausIbsen thanks for the tip. That appears to be exactly what I need for what I'm trying to achieve. However, when I add that code I receive the following errors. `The attribute "name" is undefined for the annotation type header.` `The attribute "optional" is undefined for the annotation type header.` I'll do some research and see if I have an outdated version or something else going on. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Oh the optional attribute does not exists, it was just an idea to add to a future Camel release.

Comment: I logged a ticket about this idea: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6768